# Read image object form excel.interop.hyperlink

Tags: c#

Using c# how can I assign interop.hyperlink's image to System.Drawing.Image.
Does this type of conversion exists?

Comment: Are you really trying to convert an hyperlink to an image?
Can you be more precise with your question? Show us some code, what have you done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is impossible to do directly (retrieve the image from the excel.interop.hyperlink)

However, you could potentially use the Clipboard as an intermediary to get the data as suggested [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/25049-Reading-images-from-Excel-using-office-interop.aspx)

Code Snippet :

```
Excel.Picture pic = (Excel.Picture)CurSheet.Pictures(1);
pic.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

Image pic2 = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
pic2.Save("pic.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[Here's another example](http://joymonscode.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/reading-image-from-excel-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time and response.
I've been through it. But the problem with it is the image doesn't show up in the order as they are positioned.

Comment: There is not only one image but many.
And the use case is I want to past that image into another folder or location serially as they were pasted in excel.

Comment: So you need to iterate through, and sort them by their position in the worksheet, using the pic.TopLeftCell property or whatever is important to you.

The Images don't belong to a specific cell or row, and only have their own positioning so the concept of ordering here in what's returned is a bit flaky, you will probably have to sort them on your end.

Comment: Yes.
But for now I'm directly getting the image file from the address assigned to the hyperlink.
This was a little difficult because excel doesn't store the absolute path to the hyperlink's item.
So, I had to combine the path of the excel sheet and the relative path provided by hyperlink.